# Adding an action (reset) button to the R shiny DT table

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinyapps

I modified the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465710/setting-a-default-datatable-and-replacing-it-with-a-suitable-file-type-in-r-shin/74466536#74466536) to include a save button as well. I want the user to be able to reset to the initial table after uploading a new file by adding a reset button (similar to the save button), but I wonder if it's possible to do so.

**EDIT:**
I want the button to be a part of the DT table and be placed next to the save.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
  
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fileInput("upload", NULL, accept = c(".csv")),
  DTOutput("head")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    dataframe = data.frame(
      x = seq(1:12),
      y = LETTERS[1:12])
  )
  
  observe({
    req(input$upload)
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)
    rv$dataframe   <- switch(ext,
                             csv =  read.csv(input$upload$datapath),
                             NULL)
  })
  
  
  output$head <- renderDT({
    validate(need(!is.null(rv$dataframe)," Please upload a .csv file"))
    
    datatable(rv$dataframe, extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons = list(list( extend = 'csv',
                                     filename = '//public/comments/comments.csv',
                                     text = 'Save'))))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a snapshot of the current version:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways to handle this. Here is one of it -

- Used a fixed dataframe `mtcars[1:6, 1:6]` as the default dataframe instead of one which generates random numbers which is difficult to compare imo.
- Added an `actionButton` for Reset feature.
- Created another reactive variable called  `dataframe_copy` which always holds the default dataframe.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fileInput("upload", NULL, accept = c(".csv")),
  DTOutput("head"), 
  actionButton('reset', 'Reset')
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    dataframe = mtcars[1:6, 1:6], 
    dataframe_copy = mtcars[1:6, 1:6]
  )
  
  observe({
    req(input$upload)
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)
    rv$dataframe   <- switch(ext,
                             csv =  read.csv(input$upload$datapath),
                             NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    rv$dataframe <- rv$dataframe_copy
  })
  
  output$head <- renderDT({
    validate(need(!is.null(rv$dataframe)," Please upload a .csv file"))
    
    datatable(rv$dataframe, extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons = list(list( extend = 'csv',
                                     filename = '//public/comments/comments.csv',
                                     text = 'Save'))))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I mean as a part of the table like the save button. I wan to place it next to the save. is it a way to do in such a way?
I will add further info to my main question